# How To Parse a Scientific Notation Value Back To Original Value When Reading CSV In C#

Tags: c#, csv

I am working on a weather map application that imports csv files via a url. The date fields inside the csv are stored as a string like 201601280330, which would be today's date 1/28/2016 3:30. However, when reading the csv via a streamreader the value is coming back in scientific notation like 2.01601E+11. Nothing I have tried seems to return the whole value 201601280330.

For example:

`var date = "2.01601E+11";` 
`var d = Decimal.Parse(date, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float);`

returns `201601000000` chopping off the remaining part of the string. Does anyone know a way to return the full value. When I save the `csv` locally as a text file the correct value `201601280330` is saved rather than `2.01601E+11`. Anyway to get this in the code without having to save first? I am using the code below to read the `csv` file.

```
    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromCSVFile(string path)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');

                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    if (header.Contains("ERROR:"))
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    dt.Columns.Add(header);
                }
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                    {
                        dr[i] = rows[i];
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**

Although this does not provide a technical answer to the problem I was experiencing it might provide a better explanation and help others if they experience this. Some of the example csv files sent to me for testing had been edited in Excel to make the csv smaller and then saved. After further testing, it looks like the issue occurs only for the csv files edited in Excel. Tentatively, this solves the problem for me since we won't be downloading the csv files and editing them in Excel, rather pulling them straight from a url. The code I posted above will read a the correct value without notation while for the csv edited in Excel it will only read the value with scientific notation. Unless I am wrong, I assume Excel must add something to edited csv files that prevents the value from being read correctly.

Comment: Are you sure that the value is not stored that way in the CSV? You are doing a `sr.ReadLine()` which will return the string text that is in the file.  There no conversion it is doing. How are your `DataRow` columns defined?  When you set the value on the column, you may have to cast it appropriately for that column type.

Comment: How are you verifying the value after it's read? In the debugger?

Comment: If "201601280330" is what's in the file, then reading that in from the stream is not the problem. Are you using a GridView with this DataTable to view it, by chance? Is that where you're seeing the scientific notation?

Comment: If I use Excel to open the csv then it does show the notation like 2.01601E+11 for the date column. However in the formula bar when choosing the particular cell I can see the value I want 201601010200. What we are doing is taking only rows that match sever weather and creating a new datatable based off of two csv files. The final datatable will be exported to our database and those new entries will show on a map. Ideally that is the process. I was trying to avoid saving the csv an manipulating the column via Excel in the code.

Comment: To repeat @spender: How are you verifying the value after it's been read in? Please show the code you are using to programatically retrieve the value from the `DataTable`.

Comment: @spender Yes, I am using the debugger and can see that the value is a string.

Comment: @chase If I loop through each DataRow item in the DataTable.Rows I am retrieving the date field like item.Field<string>(0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original answer questioned whether you were using Excel, but as you hadn't mentioned that in your question I was *rightly* told that I was off topic, so I changed it. Now that you have provided a follow-up answer that does mention Excel I have changed it back, here is what I wrote originally:

> Once the value has been converted into scientific notation it cannot be converted back. It is a limitation of Excel that is performing this conversion. If, when importing the data you choose a column type of Text (rather than General), then the data will be imported verbatim and Excel won't convert it into scientific notation.

As I suspected, it is Excel (not your code) that is changing the numerical data into scientific notation. I have seen this problem many times and suggest people **DO NOT** open CSV files using Excel. If you have to, then import rather than open so you can specify the data types of your numerical columns.

Comment: Don't think this is an Excel problem. The data in the csv file is correct, according to OP, so no conversion has occurred yet.

Comment: I didn't see Excel mentioned anywhere in OPs question and they've verified that the source data they are reading is not in scientific format.

Comment: Sorry about that, I rushed into my answer without fully reading the question. I have updated my it to be a bit more helpful.

Comment: @Owain Williams I tried your recommendation but still get the same result.  Based on your initial response can you answer this? If I save the csv file, rename with a .txt extension, and then open as a text file the value I need is there not in scientific notation? Seems like there would be a way to get this in code without having to save the csv.

Comment: I have updated my answer again to talk about Excel. I suggest you do not open CSV files in Excel as the default behaviour is to convert numerical data into scientific notation if it is larger than a 32-bit integer. Instead of opening the CSV, import it into Excel and specify a column type of Text for your numerical data.

Comment: @Owain Williams Thanks, I believe your answer provides the best explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Although this does not provide a technical answer to the problem I was experiencing it might provide a better explanation and help others if they experience this. Some of the example csv files sent to me for testing had been edited in Excel to make the csv smaller and then saved. After further testing, it looks like the issue occurs only for the csv files edited in Excel. Tentatively, this solves the problem for me since we won't be downloading the csv files and editing them in Excel, rather pulling them straight from a url. The code I posted above will read a the correct value without notation while for the csv edited in Excel it will only read the value with scientific notation. Unless I am wrong, I assume Excel must add something to edited csv files that prevents the value from being read correctly.